# GTFS to graph conversion?

Tags: graph, data-conversion, directed-graph, gtfs

I aim to "translate" GTFS files (non realtime) into directed graphs. Is there any API / tool that can do that easily ? I would like to create a graph per route in my GTFS, and then store it into a file.

So far I made a few tests using Python and [pygtfs](https://github.com/jarondl/pygtfs), or R and [gtfsr](https://github.com/ropensci/gtfsr), but none seems to be able to make that conversion.

Comment: Check out OpenTripPlanner: https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner

Comment: No satisfying solution existing in python to my knowledge. I had to do the same thing in my job, I was using pygtfs at first till I found it too slow and jumpy (few public feeds acutally really respect the standart) and memory hungry, so I ended up parsing the feeds myself, and building a home made graph from it, was not too long. Code ain't open or I'd give it to you though, sorry.
So if you go for python, and wanna deal with the large feeds (switzerland, paris, NY state ...), I'd advice you to dodge pygtfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [peartree](https://pypi.org/project/peartree/). Their websites says: "peartree is a library for converting GTFS feed schedules into a representative directed network graph."